# Pandas regex to return any string that contains U or UN with a digit

Tags: python, regex, django, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column with values from another columns string
What I want is to create a new column with unit values.

The position of the units can vary.

The examples of my strings are

```
this is a string and we have 4U to use
this is another string 5UN
only 6U to use today
```

I need to extract the numbers that are joined to both U and UN since the positions vary.

```
df['test_units'] = df['ITEM_DESC'].str.get(r'\(*U.*?\)',)
df['test_units']
```

This is my regex but I return only nan values.

How do I just return the number that's joined to a U Or UN?

Comment: Try `df['test_units'] = df['ITEM_DESC'].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)UN?\b')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
df['test_units'] = df['ITEM_DESC'].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)UN?\b')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PzNHoW/1). Note the unescaped pair of parentheses that form a *capturing group* whose value is returned by [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

The regex matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `U` - `U`
- `N?` - an optional `N`
- `\b` - word boundary

Pandas test:

```
import pandas as pd
cols={'ITEM_DESC': ['this is a string and we have 4U to use','this is another string 5UN','only 6U to use today']}
df = pd.DataFrame(cols)
df['test_units'] = df['ITEM_DESC'].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)UN?\b')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                ITEM_DESC test_units
0  this is a string and we have 4U to use  4        
1  this is another string 5UN              5        
2  only 6U to use today                    6        
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i'll have to refer to this example for future regex!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want U OR UN? This is because you might have something like 5UD that you don't want?
In any case:

```
patt = re.compile(r"\d+UN?\b")
```